# Highcharts: Change Highlight Color of Column Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

How can I change the background/highlight color of the column group in the following fiddle to another color than the light blue that shows by default?

I have tried using `plotOptions` in various ways which all fail to accomplish the task.

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        events: {
            hover: {
                background: '#000000'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vcehgfge/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The highlighting comes from `xAxis.crosshair = true`. This seems to be undocumented, but similar in function to `tooltip.crosshairs` ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.crosshairs)), which allows you to customize the crosshair quite a bit.

You could change to instead use this object ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcehgfge/3/)):

```
xAxis: {
    crosshair: {
        color: 'pink'
    }
}
```

Which is equivalent in appearance to this ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcehgfge/4/)):

```
tooltip: {
    crosshairs: {
        color: 'pink'
    }
}
```

It may be that the latter is preffered, since it is actually documented.

Comment: perfect! i would have never guessed the `crosshair` options.. thank you!

Comment: For posterity:  Per the documentation, as of 4.1 `tooltip.crosshairs` has been deprecated and `xAxis.crosshair` is the official solution.