# How can I change the color of plot bands in Highchart basic column chart?

Tags: highcharts

I opened the basic column chart using Highcharts and now I need to make little customization. I would like to change the color of the plot band that is visible when I place the mouse pointer within one category on X axis. I tried to use the xAxis -> plotBand option, but it only changes the color with specific start and end values. How could I change this color on mouseover?
This is some example, how I would like it to look: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ilxhd99xo8pwn7v/Zrzut%20ekranu%202015-09-05%2020.20.17.png?dl=0

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31949141/2732991

Comment: Yes, this is exactly, what I needed. Thank you very much. Although there was another issue, that the highlated area had covered grid lines, but the property zindex did the job.